# Overriding toString to return more than one variable

Tags: android

I have a Story class with the following variables, which correspondent to database columns:

```
int id;
String title;
int author_id;
String collection;
String body;
```

I have overridden `toString()` to return `title` like so:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

With this setup, I can successfully pull all story titles from my database.

But what if I also want to pull all story collections? Is it possible to return more than one variable in the override, or should I look at another approach?

Answer (score 1):

The toString generates a String representation of your object as a human readable text, you can concatenate the result of many vars AS a String

```
return title + " " + collection;
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I change this to display a ListView of titles and a separate ListView of collections?

Comment: You mean to the UI, you need to write an adapter, but that was nt your question

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple returns out of the box. I think your best options would be to either:

- Encapsulate the data that you want to return into a simple Java class, so you can set the fields and return it as one object.

In a function that returns your object, when you are getting ready to return:

```
MyReturnObject obj = new MyReturnObject();
obj.setTitle(title);
obj.setCollection(collection);
return obj;
```

- Alternatively you can return the collections with some sort of delimiter, so that you can extract the data you want later on: `return title + "|" + collections;`

This will leave you with a String like: `myTitle|collection1|collection2|collection3`, which you can parse by `String[] tokens = myString.split("|");`

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your first option, do you mean that I should have two separate classes and return `title` in one and `collection` in the other?

Comment: Won't I need to return a String inside `@Override public String toString() {}`? I can't apply a `setTitle` or `setCollection` method to a String.

Comment: Right so the only option in the `toString` method is going to be the delimiter approach. Return some sort of delimited string and then parse it.